# Why won't Splash render this webpage?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm quite new to Splash and tho I was able to get Splash setup on my Ubuntu 18 (via Splash/Docker) it gives me different results for this page:
https://www.overstock.com/Home-Garden/Area-Rugs/31446/subcat.html

Normally it's rendered like so:
[image]

But when I try to render it in Splash, it renders it like this:
[image]

I have tried changing the user agent in Splash to this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
```

Consequently, this makes the Splash script like so:

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash:set_user_agent(
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'
  )
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Yet, despite these additions, it still fails to render the page.

How can I get Splash to render this page?

Comment: the docker splash is pretty outdated if you want a quick solution go with scrapy-selenium.
if you want splash you have to install it manually and modify it

Comment: @wishmaster, Do you mean putting scrapy-selenium into the same docker as Splash?

Comment: no need for splash at all if you go with selenium (scrapy-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `overstock.com` requires a `Connection` and `Accept` headers. Add it to your request and it should work as expected.
Tested on Postman, with and without the `Connection: keep-alive` && `Accept: */*`  headers; I get the same error page:

[image]

After adding the two headers above:

[image]

Therefor your request should be edited accordingly:

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash:set_custom_headers({
     ["Connection"] = "keep-alive",
     ["Accept"] = "*/*",
  })
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Comment: Still got same result after using this.

Comment: @rom still my guess is that you're missing a request header. Try working with an API development platform such as Postman to replicate the issue you're getting outside of Splash and play around with the headers.